# Bootstrap navbar margins

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I'd like to make the left and right margins of the navbar conetnt smaller so the "brand" (left most component) appears more on the left then the default and same for the right component.

Can somebody point me to relevant less variables to modify?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

With a basic layout, the CSS selector you want is

```
body > .navbar .brand
```

Play with margin-left and margin-right until you get the result you want. Depending on how you are calling your CSS styles, you may need to add !important as well, eg

```
body > .navbar .brand{
margin-left:-20px !important;
margin-right:-20px !important;  
}
```

If you don't have any success with this, try ommitting *body >*

**EDIT**

If you want to change the width of the entire navbar, try something like

```
.navbar{
margin-left:-20px;
margin-right:-20px;
}
```

You might also need to adjust the details for navbar-inner, eg

```
.navbar-inner{
padding-left:0;
padding-right:0;
}
```

**Edit**
See if this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/zBeZF/

Good luck!

Comment: I think that applies only to .brand component, correct?  How about the component that is floating right? I'd like the margins of both sides to be smaller. Thanks

Comment: OK I modified the navbar.less file (working with less directly) and added the margins and recompiled. It does not seem to work.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you need to achieve, see if my additional note about navbar-inner helps

Comment: Take a look at this bootstrap example.  I am trying to shift text "project name" (.brand) more to the left (10px) and the same for any components that would be floating right (more to the right by 10px). http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/starter-template.html

Comment: seems to work if I set the margin of the container to 0 e.g .navbar .container{margin:0;} Can someone confirm I am not breaking anything by doing this or if i need to modify anything else.

Comment: Adjusting the .navbar .container value is fine. It's having a similar effect as what I mentioned for .navbar-inner, except that it will move .brand more than 10px